# How should jQuery execute on .html() elements?

Tags: jquery, html

What is the appropriate way to use jquery statements on HTML elements you added during a function call?

```
Reset: function() {
$("#viewarea").empty();

Loader: function() {
Reset();

$("#viewarea").html(//HTML CODE);
$(function() {
    $("#viewarea").each(function(index){
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

My code has this Loader function that will clear a div element and add content to the page. When I want to switch to a new page I clear the entire viewarea and write new content so I do not have to reload the page. My problem is that I have elements being drawn to the page and the jQuery selector will not FIND these elements. Right now jquery statements execute on document ready but even without that it will not find the elements.

I think the solution should be some type of method that will make the jquery statement wait on $().html() to be done before trying to find elements on the page.

Comment: In what jquery statements does it not find the elements in the newly added DOM contents? Just curious. A cut down sample for context?

Comment: it seems `$("#viewarea").each` has no sense.

Comment: isn't it better to use `append()` instead of `html()`, thus DOM will be built depending on appended objects

Comment: Ah - Is the point that the console.log of the new contents does not produce anything because the new html elements have not at that point in time completed loading into the DOM? Have you tried  `$("#viewarea").append(html code)`

Comment: No but I don't see difference between HTML and append. My jquery $(view area).each() should return all elements but sometimes the log will miss elements . this from console log refers to all elements in viewarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is actually correct but I forgot that this was inside a AJAX call which is asynchronous. So my elements were being drawn but it skip straight to my jquery and started to execute them but sometimes the AJAX would finish before then sometimes not. Lesson learned, you can use html and append and use jquery statements but be sure that they are not in an asynchronous statement.